# BeforeRightClick acts only on PREVIOUSLY clicked cell

Tags: vba, userform

I'm very new to excel VBA, I've searched many posts and sites, but cannot find out why...

My Goal:
Right click on a cell, a form with a textbox opens, the clicked cell's address is shown in the textbox.

I've tried some very standard code... like so:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    UserForm1.Show
    With UserForm1.TextBox1
     .Text = Target.Address
    End With
    End Sub
```

Here's the bug (step by step of my test results)

```
1. I right click A1, the form opens, textbox displays null.
2. I right click D3, the form opens, NOW the textbox displays A1.
3. I right click E4, the form opens, NOW the textbox displays D3.
```

The textbox always displays the address of the *previously right-clicked cell*. I need the textbox to display the address of what I just right-clicked.

Please provide some insight on why this happens and how to correct this, thanks guys!

Comment: Title says BeforeDoubleClick ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event routine is okay, `target` is the cell you are right-clicking. However, you show the form before you write the address into it, and `.show` opens the form *modal*, that means you code continues only after closing the form. You simply have to revert this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    With UserForm1
        .TextBox1.Text = Target.Address
        .Show
    End With
end Sub
```